# Programatically check for mouse click in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgsmapcanvas

I want to know how to check for a mouse click in QGIS. I am trying to write a Python plugin and want to provide functionality similar to the *"Select Single Feature"* tool that already exists in QGIS.

I checked the QGIS API docs and found

```
QgsMapCanvas::CanvasProperties::mouseButtonDown
```

This sounds promising. I have a `QgsMapCanvas` object but I can't see how to access the `mouseButtonDown` attribute.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The best way to make a new tool like the Select Single Feature tool is to inherit from the [`QgsMapTool`](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapTool.html) class.  When your tool is active, which can be set using `QgsMapCanvas::setMapTool`, any keyboard or click events the canvas gets will be passed onto your custom tool.

Here is a basic `QgsMapTool` class

```
class PointTool(QgsMapTool):   
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas    

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        pass

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()

        point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #Get the click
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()

        point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)

    def activate(self):
        pass

    def deactivate(self):
        pass

    def isZoomTool(self):
        return False

    def isTransient(self):
        return False

    def isEditTool(self):
        return True
```

You can do what you need in `canvasReleaseEvent`, etc

To set this tool active you just do:

```
tool = PointTool(qgis.iface.mapCanvas())
qgis.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its exactly what I need. However, when I try implementing this solution I get the following error: `class PointTool(QgsMapTool):
NameError: name 'QgsMapTool' is not defined`. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to use `from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool` at the top

Comment: Last question... How do you then deactivate this tool?

Comment: Set maptool to something else, or to `None`.  I would save what the user had selected using `QgsMapCanvas.mapTool()` restoring it after you are done.

Comment: @NathanW "To set maptool to something else" also means that I click 'Pan Map' on the toolbar, right?

Comment: @NathanW I use setMapTool(...) in a plug in code but the release event doesn't fire. I use the following commands: `tool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())` and `self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)`

Comment: Since QGIS 2.12, there is no longer a need to do the coordiante dance manually. A simple `point = e.mapPoint()` is enough, it even supports `e.snapPoint()` http://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapMouseEvent.html.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this with a combination of using QGIS "canvasClicked" but also SIGNAL/SLOTS to deal with the response:

```
result = QObject.connect(self.clickTool, SIGNAL("canvasClicked(const QgsPoint &, Qt::MouseButton)"), self.handleMouseDown)
```

Not tried but should give you some more information to start looking at. There is [a tutorial here](http://www.qgisworkshop.org/html/workshop/plugins_tutorial.html) where someone is using this to build a very basic plugin.

Comment: They are using the built in `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` class which will give you the basic start for a tool.  A good way to connect to signals in PyQt is using this syntax `self.clickTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.handleMouseDown)`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this (this is to select a point):

```
def run(self):
    self.pointEmitter = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.iface.mapCanvas())
    QObject.connect( self.pointEmitter, SIGNAL("canvasClicked(const QgsPoint, Qt::MouseButton)"), self.selectNow)
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( self.pointEmitter )

def selectNow(self, point, button):
  #QMessageBox.information(None, "Clicked coords", " x: " + str(point.x()) + " Y: " + str(point.y()) )

  layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
  if not layer or layer.type() != QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
     QMessageBox.warning(None, "No!", "Select a vector layer")
     return

  width = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapUnitsPerPixel() * 2
  rect = QgsRectangle(point.x() - width,
                      point.y() - width,
                      point.x() + width,
                      point.y() + width)

  rect = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().mapToLayerCoordinates(layer, rect)

  layer.select([], rect)
  feat = QgsFeature()

  ids = []
  while layer.nextFeature(feat):
    ids.append( feat.id() )

  layer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
```

Comment: I would use the `self.clickTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.handleMouseDown)` syntax to connect to signals as it's much cleaner.