# Retrieve point coordinates from map canvas using QGIS API

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I'm trying to build a plugin that firstly captures the map coordinates.

I have tried to adapt the map tool explained in this post: [How to programatically check for a mouse click in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/how-to-programatically-check-for-a-mouse-click-in-qgis)

The code I used for the main function is below:

```
def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
    #Get the click
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()

    canvas = self.canvas
    canvas.mapRenderer().setProjectionsEnabled(True)
    canvas.mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(27700))
    espg = canvas.mapRenderer().destinationCrs().authid()

    point = self.canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
```

Unfortunately the when I print point it always returns as (0,0). I have tried various ways to set the crs of the points but none work.  What needs to be done to make it work?

Comment: Does print on x,y return anything?

Comment: Also don't do setProjectionsEnabled or setDestinationCrs.  That is changing the canvas itself which might not be what you want. Use `QgsCoordinateTransform` if you need to transform from one to the other, or just `toMapCoordinates` is enough to go from click to canvas coordinates

Comment: Thanks @Nathan W - I was just being explicit with the crs to make sure it wasn't that.

Comment: print x, print y does return values. These aren't recognisable to me though. All are three digit couplets like 356,172?

Comment: Yeah they are the screen coordinates. Remove the other lines and just have the toMapCoordinates stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
class PointTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
def __init__(self, canvas):
    QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, canvas)

def canvasReleaseEvent(self, mouseEvent):
    qgsPoint = self.toMapCoordinates(mouseEvent.pos())
    print('x:', qgsPoint.x(), ', y:', qgsPoint.y())
```

As your question is possibly a duplicate to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/point-click-for-coordinates-stand-alone-qgis-in-python).