# QgsMapCanvas object is not callable (Ubuntu with, Eclipse, Python & QGIS 2.0)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, standalone

I'm basically borrowing the code for picking up a coordinate from a mouse click from this answer :

[How to programatically check for a mouse click in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/how-to-programatically-check-for-a-mouse-click-in-qgis)

However in a stand alone application I do not have access to `iface`, so am instead calling the class with :

```
tool = PointTool(self.map_canvas()) 
self.map_canvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

Intellisense finds the `map_canvas` ok and it compiles, but I am getting a run time error:

```
'QgsMapCanvas' object not callable
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi, I have not had time to check if my understanding of this fixed the issue yet. I will look at it tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention if you're doing it, but as you're writing a standalone application, you need to create a Map Canvas by yourself, in this way:

```
self.map_canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
```

Then you can set the map tool using `self.map_canvas`:

```
tool = PointTool( self.map_canvas ) 
self.map_canvas.setMapTool( tool )
```

---

**Why not to write the parenthesis in `self.map_canvas`?**

Because you already have instantiated the `QgsMapCanvas` class, it's now an object and you don't call objects, you call methods or functions, such as `iface.mapCanvas()` (here you call a function of `iface` that returns the QGIS map canvas) or `QgsMapCanvas()` (here you call the constructor of the class, which is still a method).