# `NameError: name `qgis` is not defined` in QGIS Plugins

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

In the QGIS (2.99) Python Console, the name/variable `qgis` seems to be automatically defined.

However, in writing a plugin, there is an error whenever I refer to `qgis`. For example, in I have `qgis.iface.mapCanvas()` in my *Plugin*'s `initGui(self)' function, I get an error

```
NameError: name `qgis` is not defined
```

How can fix this error?

By the way, I am trying to put the following code from this GIS.SE answer(https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/45105) into my plugin

```
tool = PointTool(qgis.iface.mapCanvas())
qgis.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

The code works fine inside QGIS main window (in Python Console), but generates the above error when moving it into the Plugin. I can't figure out how to let the `PointTool` respond inside a plugin. The code for `PointTool` class from the linked answer is:

```
class PointTool(QgsMapTool):   
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, canvas)
        self.canvas = canvas    

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        pass

    ...
```

Comment: Does `qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()` not work in your plugin or is `qgis.utils` now obsolete?

Answer (score 5):

When you create a plugin, you receiv `iface` via the `__init__` function :

```
def __init__(self, iface):
   self.iface = iface
```

After that in you code you can access to `iface` via `self.iface`.

Otherwise you can have access via `qgis.utils.iface`

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer - it works for me by simply adding this def and then changing any references.