# How to solve error: global name 'qgis' is not defined

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgsmapcanvas

I use this code as a rubber from my QGIS canvas:

```py
def obrisi_sve(iface):
    rubber = [i for i in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items() if issubclass(type(i), qgis.utils.gui.QgsRubberBand)]
    for ver in rubber:
        if ver in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
            iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(ver)
```

When I run it from Python console inside QGIS it works ok, but when I use it in plugin I get error: `global name 'qgis' is not defined`. To call this file 
from plugin I use these lines of code:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from math import *
import os

import brisanje_rubber

from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic
from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject
from PyQt4.QtCore import SIGNAL
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis import *


def __init__(self, parent=None):
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.obrisi_IPP)
def obrisi_IPP(self):
    brisanje_rubber.obrisi_sve(iface)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/249635/43

Comment: I tried, but it didn't help

Comment: Is QgsRubberBand under qgis.utils.gui?  Is it not under just qgis.gui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a plugin you need to import the modules.
On the other hand, this is **not correct** `qgis.utils.gui.QgsRubberBand`

**Sample**

```
from qgis.gui import QgsRubberBand
from qgis.utils import iface

def obrisi_sve(iface):
    rubber = [i for i in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items() if issubclass(type(i), QgsRubberBand)]
    for ver in rubber:
        if ver in iface.mapCanvas().scene().items():
            iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(ver)
```